# mysql get quantity by date and time

Tags: mysql

Can someone point me to the right direction for a query that i can't make it working like i want.

This is my table

```
id_req  id_item  id_user  startDate   startTime  endDate     endTime    quant  created     
------  -------  -------  ----------  ---------  ----------  --------  ------  ------------
 9       10        1  2015-11-19  10:00:00   2015-11-19  11:50:00      23  2015-11-06  
10       10        1  2015-11-19  10:00:00   2015-11-19  11:50:00      23  2015-11-06
```

As you can see i have ordered the same id item in the same date and time with 23 (quantity). suppose that i have only 40, so i can't get this insert since i don't have enought itens, so what i want is before the insert check how many are available at that moment

I have tried this but error

```
    SELECT req.`quant`, SUM(req.`quant`) AS grand_total, 
    FROM requisicoes req
        JOIN item i ON i.`quantidade` = req.`quant` 
    WHERE req.`id_item` = 9 
      AND req.`startDate` = "2015-11-19" AND req.`endDate` = "2015-11-19" 
    GROUP BY req.`id_item`
```

UPDATE

Thanks, i'm almost there, the correct query is :

```
    SELECT SUM(i.`quantidade`-r.`quant`) AS total 
    FROM `requisicoes` AS r 
        INNER JOIN `item` AS i ON (r.`id_item` = i.`id_itens`) 
    WHERE r.`startDate` = "2015-11-20" AND r.`endDate` = "2015-11-20" 
      AND r.`startTime` = "12:00:00" AND r.`endTime` = "12:50:00"
```

But when i have a loan it gives the right value, when i don't have it gives me null instead of the right quantity

UPDATE 2

Table item

```
id_itens  nome                                                       descricao                          data        quantidade  id_tipo  id_estado  
--------  ---------------------------------------------------------  ---------------------------------  ----------  ----------  -------  -----------
   4  Ser Global -                                               Módulos 5, 6                       2015-09-30          45        1            0
   7  Ser Global - Área de Integração - Ensino Profissional      Módulos 5, 6 (12.º ano / ano 3)    2015-09-25          30        1            1
   8  Ser Global - Área de Integração - Ensino Profissional      Módulos 5, 6 (12.º ano / ano 3)    2015-09-25          30        1            1
  10  Ser Global - Área de Integração - Ensino Profissional      Módulos 5, 6 (12.º ano / ano 3)    2015-09-25          30        1            1
  11  Ser Global - Área de Integração - Ensino Profissional      Módulos 5, 6 (12.º ano / ano 3)    2015-09-25          30        1            1
  12  Ser Global - Área de Integração - Ensino Profissional      Módulos 5, 6 (12.º ano / ano 3)    2015-09-25          30        1            1
  13  Portatil                                                   Asus Zenbook                       2015-09-25           3        2            1
  14  Portatil                                                   Asus UX31                          2015-09-25           3        2            0
```

Table requisições

```
id_req  id_item  id_user  startDate   startTime  endDate     endTime    quant  created
```

---

```
 9       10        1  2015-11-19  10:00:00   2015-11-19  11:50:00      23  2015-11-06  
10       10        1  2015-11-20  10:00:00   2015-11-20  11:50:00      12  2015-11-06
```

The query returns

### total

(NULL)

if the time is null and i want to have the full quantity if the book is not borrowed.

The query

```
SELECT SUM(i.`quantidade`-r.`quant`) AS total 
  FROM `requisicoes` AS r
 INNER JOIN `item` AS i ON (r.`id_item` = i.`id_itens`)
 WHERE r.`startDate` = "2015-11-20"
  AND r.`endDate` = "2015-11-20"
  AND r.`startTime` = "12:00:00" AND r.`endTime` = "12:50:00"
```

Comment: Two things: First, please give the error message, the other table, and the desired result.  Second:  You're misusing the nasty MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. Read this:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: check my update please

Comment: `But when i have a loan` where have you mentioned a **loan** anywhere in your question or your query?

Comment: or i.id_item.    @op you should either post the table definition or the error message.  best would be both.

Comment: No, the fields are correct, i will update my post with table definition in few moments

Comment: Any reason why you are using a seperate date and time, instead of a datetime?

Comment: The school want's like this, i would prefer datetime

Comment: split date and time: stupid professor tricks. put that in your "never again" file.